# Почему данный код не работает в IE 7?

Tags: javascript

В хроме все ок.

```
document.getElementById('doo').onclick = function () {
    if (this.value == this.defaultValue) this.value = ''
}
document.getElementById('doo').onblur = function () {
    if (this.value == '') this.value = this.defaultValue
}
```

Comment: выделите код и нажмите кнопку Код...ничего не понятно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это так надо оформлять для начала, чтобы пользователям понятно было.

```
   document.getElementById('doo').onclick = function (){
        if(this.value == this.defaultValue) {
            this.value = '';
        };
    };
    document.getElementById('doo').onblur = function (){
        if(this.value == ''){
            this.value = this.defaultValue;
        };
    };
```

Это вам функция для добавления событий, самая простая и универсальная.

```
function addEvent(elem, type, handler){
    if (elem.addEventListener){
        elem.addEventListener(type, handler, false);
    } else {
        elem.attachEvent("on"+type, handler);
    };
};
```

Соответственно вот так её можно использовать:

```
var id = document.getElementById('doo');

addEvent(id, 'click', reset);
addEvent(id, 'blur', defaultval);

function reset() {
    if(this.value == this.defaultValue) {
        this.value = '';
    };
};
function defaultval() {
    if(this.value == ''){
        this.value = this.defaultValue;
    };
};
```

Попробуйте должно все работать!